# Java console code for StopWatch/Timer?

Tags: java

I have the required code for the stopwatch here. All i want is get rid of the Swing part here and display the same output in console. Can anybody help?

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.text.*;

public class ElapsedTime extends JFrame
{
JLabel time;

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

ElapsedTime()
{
setSize(380,200);
setTitle("http://simpleandeasycodes.blogspot.com/");
setLocation(100,100);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

time = new JLabel("");

time.setFont(new Font("SansSerif",Font.BOLD, 36));

time.setForeground(Color.MAGENTA);

add(time);

//starting new Thread which will update time
new Thread(new Runnable()
{
public void run() 
{ try 
{
updateTime(); 
} 
catch (Exception ie) 
{ }
}
}).start();
}

public void updateTime()
{
try
{
while(true)
{
//geting Time in desire format
time.setText(getTimeElapsed());
//Thread sleeping for 1 sec
Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
}
}
catch (Exception e)
{
System.out.println("Exception in Thread Sleep : "+e);
}
}

public String getTimeElapsed()
{
long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
elapsedTime = elapsedTime / 1000;

String seconds = Integer.toString((int)(elapsedTime % 60));
String minutes = Integer.toString((int)((elapsedTime % 3600) / 60));
String hours = Integer.toString((int)(elapsedTime / 3600));

if (seconds.length() < 2)
seconds = "0" + seconds;

if (minutes.length() < 2)
minutes = "0" + minutes;

if (hours.length() < 2)
hours = "0" + hours;

return minutes+":"+seconds;
}

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
JFrame obj = new ElapsedTime();
obj.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Comment: So you want your program to count time, basically? Must it clear the console when updating the time, or would it be acceptable to print each increment of time on a new line?

Comment: [Java: time elapsed counter using Swing](http://simpleandeasycodes.blogspot.com/2009/10/java-time-elsdsed-counter-using-swing.html) - BTW - is this homework?

Comment: Yes. I want my program to count time, simply. And it should clear the console when updating time(like 00:01,00:02,00:03...so on).Thanks

Comment: @ Andreas_D No!This isn't a homework. I'm quite new to Java. I have the required code but i want to get rid of Swing and do the same thing in a console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The keys are:

a.) Finding which character to write to the console in order to remove the most recently-written character (`\b`, or `\010` in ASCII)
b.) Realising that you need to remember how many characters you've written to the console the last time you updated it
c.) Remembering to use `print` instead of `println`

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    int charsWritten = 0;
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    while (1 > 0) {
      Thread.sleep(1000);
      long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - start;
      elapsedTime = elapsedTime / 1000;

      String seconds = Integer.toString((int) (elapsedTime % 60));
      String minutes = Integer.toString((int) ((elapsedTime % 3600) / 60));
      String hours = Integer.toString((int) (elapsedTime / 3600));

      if (seconds.length() < 2) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
      }

      if (minutes.length() < 2) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
      }

      if (hours.length() < 2) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
      }

      String writeThis = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

      for (int i = 0; i < charsWritten; i++) {
        System.out.print("\b");
      }
      System.out.print(writeThis);
      charsWritten = writeThis.length();
    }
  }
}
```

Note: you could be more efficient by only clearing the console up to only the characters you are changing but I figure you're not going to get that much of a speed improvement.

Comment: I'm getting the following out put exactly:

00:00:0100:00:0200:00:0300:00:0400:00:0500:00:0600:00:0700:00:0800:00:0900:00:1000:00:1100:00:1200:00:1300:00:1400:00:1500:00:1600:00:1700:00:18

???

Comment: @Maxood - It could be because the `\010` is the ASCII code for backspace and your console isn't ASCII? Anyway, I've fixed my code to use `\b` instead. Hopefully that will work for you.

Comment: @Catchwa I'm still getting a similar output and not the required one.

Comment: @Maxood - What OS? What Java version? Where are you running it (e.g. within an IDE - if so, which one)? What is the native language of your OS?

Comment: @Catchwa The OS is android. Java version is 1.6. I'm running my project in Eclipse and the native language of my OS is Java.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [StopWatch](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang/time/StopWatch.html) from [Apache Commons](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). It should fulfill your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something that i have figured out myself a little while ago:

```
public class DelayExample{
  static int i,j;
  public static void main(String[] args){

    for (j= 0; j>=0; j++)
    {
    for (i = 0; i < 60; i++)
      {
      System.out.println(j+":" + i);

      try
      {
        Thread.sleep(1000);        

            }catch (InterruptedException ie)
            {
        System.out.println(ie.getMessage());
            }
        }

    }
    }
}
```

Now i want the clear screen code in Java now. Also i think i have to use System.out.print() instead.

Answer (score 0):

So there a Swing-free solution:

```
public class ElapsedTime{

long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

public ElapsedTime() {
    try {
        while (true) {
            //Clear Console
            for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)    
                System.out.println();
            // geting Time in desire format
            System.out.println(getTimeElapsed());
            // Thread sleeping for 1 sec
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception in Thread Sleep : " + e);
    }
}

public String getTimeElapsed() {
    long elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
    elapsedTime = elapsedTime / 1000;

    String seconds = Integer.toString((int) (elapsedTime % 60));
    String minutes = Integer.toString((int) ((elapsedTime % 3600) / 60));
    String hours = Integer.toString((int) (elapsedTime / 3600));

    if (seconds.length() < 2)
        seconds = "0" + seconds;

    if (minutes.length() < 2)
        minutes = "0" + minutes;

    if (hours.length() < 2)
        hours = "0" + hours;

    return minutes + ":" + seconds;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new ElapsedTime();
}
```

}

I'm afraid there is no method to clear the console because Java is platform independant. I just insert 25 empty Lines so the last time disappears.

Comment: You're incorrect about not being able to clear the console. Password entry via the console depends on it! See http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Security/pwordmask/