# Android: How to pause and resume a Count Down Timer?

Tags: java, android, onpause, countdowntimer

I have developed a Count Down Timer and I am not sure how to pause and resume the timer as the textview for the timer is being clicked. Click to start then click again to pause and to resume, click again the timer's text view.

This is my code:

```
    Timer = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.time); //TIMER  
    Timer.setOnClickListener(TimerClickListener);
    counter = new MyCount(600000, 1000);
}//end of create 

private OnClickListener TimerClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        updateTimeTask();
    }

    private void updateTimeTask() {
        if (decision == 0) {
            counter.start();
            decision = 1;
        } else if (decision == 2) {
            counter.onResume1();
            decision = 1;
        } else {
            counter.onPause1();
            decision = 2;
        }//end if  
    }

    ;
};

class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }//MyCount  

    public void onResume1() {
        onResume();
    }

    public void onPause1() {
        onPause();
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        Timer.setText("00:00");
        p1++;
        if (p1 <= 4) {
            TextView PScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pscore);
            PScore.setText(p1 + "");
        }//end if  
    }//finish  

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Integer milisec = new Integer(new Double(millisUntilFinished).intValue());
        Integer cd_secs = milisec / 1000;

        Integer minutes = (cd_secs % 3600) / 60;
        Integer seconds = (cd_secs % 3600) % 60;

        Timer.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":"
                + String.format("%02d", seconds));
        ///long timeLeft = millisUntilFinished / 1000;  
        /}//on tick  
}//class MyCount  

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //handler.removeCallbacks(updateTimeTask);  
    //handler.postDelayed(updateTimeTask, 1000);  
}//onResume  

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    //do stuff  
}//onPause
```

Comment: This will surelyhelp you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510433/countdown-timer-required-on-android

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: do I need to use crono for pause and resume?

Comment: you must see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8858608/3496570

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
/*
 * Copyright (C) 2010 Andrew Gainer
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

// Adapted from Android's CountDownTimer class

package com.cycleindex.multitimer;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.os.SystemClock;

/**
 * Schedule a countdown until a time in the future, with
 * regular notifications on intervals along the way.
 *
  * The calls to {@link #onTick(long)} are synchronized to this object so that
 * one call to {@link #onTick(long)} won't ever occur before the previous
 * callback is complete.  This is only relevant when the implementation of
 * {@link #onTick(long)} takes an amount of time to execute that is significant
 * compared to the countdown interval.
 */
public abstract class CountDownTimerWithPause {

    /**
     * Millis since boot when alarm should stop.
     */
  private long mStopTimeInFuture;

  /**
   * Real time remaining until timer completes
   */
    private long mMillisInFuture;

    /**
     * Total time on timer at start
     */
    private final long mTotalCountdown;

    /**
     * The interval in millis that the user receives callbacks
     */
    private final long mCountdownInterval;

    /**
     * The time remaining on the timer when it was paused, if it is currently paused; 0 otherwise.
     */
    private long mPauseTimeRemaining;

    /**
     * True if timer was started running, false if not.
     */
    private boolean mRunAtStart;

    /**
     * @param millisInFuture The number of millis in the future from the call
     *   to {@link #start} until the countdown is done and {@link #onFinish()}
     *   is called
     * @param countDownInterval The interval in millis at which to execute
     *   {@link #onTick(millisUntilFinished)} callbacks
     * @param runAtStart True if timer should start running, false if not
     */
    public CountDownTimerWithPause(long millisOnTimer, long countDownInterval, boolean runAtStart) {
        mMillisInFuture = millisOnTimer;
        mTotalCountdown = mMillisInFuture;
        mCountdownInterval = countDownInterval;
        mRunAtStart = runAtStart;
    }

    /**
     * Cancel the countdown and clears all remaining messages
     */
    public final void cancel() {
        mHandler.removeMessages(MSG);
    }

    /**
     * Create the timer object.
     */
    public synchronized final CountDownTimerWithPause create() {
        if (mMillisInFuture <= 0) {
            onFinish();
        } else {
          mPauseTimeRemaining = mMillisInFuture;
        }

        if (mRunAtStart) {
          resume();
        }

        return this;
    }

    /**
     * Pauses the counter.
     */
  public void pause () {
    if (isRunning()) {
      mPauseTimeRemaining = timeLeft();
      cancel();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Resumes the counter.
   */
  public void resume () {
    if (isPaused()) {
      mMillisInFuture = mPauseTimeRemaining;
      mStopTimeInFuture = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mMillisInFuture;
          mHandler.sendMessage(mHandler.obtainMessage(MSG));
      mPauseTimeRemaining = 0;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Tests whether the timer is paused.
   * @return true if the timer is currently paused, false otherwise.
   */
  public boolean isPaused () {
    return (mPauseTimeRemaining > 0);
  }

  /**
   * Tests whether the timer is running. (Performs logical negation on {@link #isPaused()})
   * @return true if the timer is currently running, false otherwise.
   */
  public boolean isRunning() {
    return (! isPaused());
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of milliseconds remaining until the timer is finished
   * @return number of milliseconds remaining until the timer is finished
   */
  public long timeLeft() {
    long millisUntilFinished;
    if (isPaused()) {
      millisUntilFinished = mPauseTimeRemaining;
    } else {
      millisUntilFinished = mStopTimeInFuture - SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
      if (millisUntilFinished < 0) millisUntilFinished = 0;
    }
    return millisUntilFinished;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of milliseconds in total that the timer was set to run
   * @return number of milliseconds timer was set to run
   */
  public long totalCountdown() {
    return mTotalCountdown;
  }

  /**
   * Returns the number of milliseconds that have elapsed on the timer.
   * @return the number of milliseconds that have elapsed on the timer.
   */
  public long timePassed() {
    return mTotalCountdown - timeLeft();
  }

  /**
   * Returns true if the timer has been started, false otherwise.
   * @return true if the timer has been started, false otherwise.
   */
  public boolean hasBeenStarted() {
    return (mPauseTimeRemaining <= mMillisInFuture);
  }

    /**
     * Callback fired on regular interval
     * @param millisUntilFinished The amount of time until finished
     */
    public abstract void onTick(long millisUntilFinished);

    /**
     * Callback fired when the time is up.
     */
    public abstract void onFinish();


    private static final int MSG = 1;


    // handles counting down
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

            synchronized (CountDownTimerWithPause.this) {
                long millisLeft = timeLeft();

                if (millisLeft <= 0) {
                    cancel();
                  onFinish();
                } else if (millisLeft < mCountdownInterval) {
                    // no tick, just delay until done
                    sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), millisLeft);
                } else {
                    long lastTickStart = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
                    onTick(millisLeft);

                    // take into account user's onTick taking time to execute
                    long delay = mCountdownInterval - (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastTickStart);

                    // special case: user's onTick took more than mCountdownInterval to
                    // complete, skip to next interval
                    while (delay < 0) delay += mCountdownInterval;

                    sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(MSG), delay);
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Source : [This Gist.](https://gist.github.com/bverc/1492672)

Comment: not found :@ where is the link why its being accepted

Comment: as you can see the link was added some time ago and could expried

Comment: provide some other link or you can paste your code.

Comment: http://example.javamonday.com/Open-Source/Android/Timer/multitimer-android/com/cycleindex/multitimer/CountDownTimerWithPause.java.htm

Comment: @RishabhSrivastava you can use `create()`

Comment: Would be helpful , an example of how to use this class.

Comment: Working charm. Thank you so much. Much appreciated

Comment: how to stop timer ?  `cancel();`  is not working for me

Comment: I got this error message: "This Handler class should be static or leaks might occur"

Comment: @QuentinRufin It's actually a warning, but an important one: use of Handler is prone to memory leaks. To avoid them, be sure to clear the Hander of all messages when stopping the calling activity with Handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null).

Answer (score 18):

A nice and simple way to create a Pause/Resume for your CountDownTimer is to create a separate method for your timer **start**, **pause** and **resume** as follows:

```
public void timerStart(long timeLengthMilli) {
        timer = new CountDownTimer(timeLengthMilli, 1000) {

            @Override
            public void onTick(long milliTillFinish) {
                milliLeft=milliTillFinish;
                min = (milliTillFinish/(1000*60));
                sec = ((milliTillFinish/1000)-min*60);
                clock.setText(Long.toString(min)+":"+Long.toString(sec));
                Log.i("Tick", "Tock");
            }
         }
         timer.start();
```

The timerStart has a long parameter as it will be reused by the **resume()** method below. Remember to store your **milliTillFinished** (above as milliLeft) so that you may send it through in your **resume()** method. Pause and resume methods below respectively:

```
public void timerPause() {
        timer.cancel();
    }

    private void timerResume() {
        Log.i("min", Long.toString(min));
        Log.i("Sec", Long.toString(sec));
        timerStart(milliLeft);
    }
```

Here is the code for the button FYI:

```
startPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(startPause.getText().equals("Start")){
                    Log.i("Started", startPause.getText().toString());
                    startPause.setText("Pause");
                    timerStart(15*1000);
                } else if (startPause.getText().equals("Pause")){
                    Log.i("Paused", startPause.getText().toString());
                    startPause.setText("Resume");
                    timerPause();
                } else if (startPause.getText().equals("Resume")){
                    startPause.setText("Pause");
                    timerResume();
                }
```

Answer (score 12):

Well there are no API to pause or resume it. What you should do is `cancel()` the timer and store the time remaining in a variable. When the resume button is hit again, restart the timer with the value from the variable.

---

You know [Chronometers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152569/how-to-change-format-of-chronometer) may be of interest to you.

Comment: Hmm do I need to use savedInstanceState to store the time remaining? or I would use this: ///long timeLeft = millisUntilFinished / 1000; from my code? thanks

Comment: If you know that your Activity containing the timer is [destroyed and recreated, then yes you have to store the the timer value in `savedInstanceState`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/151940/68805)

Comment: Sorry Im new in android programming. How would I store the timer value using savedInstanceState?

Comment: Click on the link in my previous comment and see Reto's answer

Comment: I cannot apply it on my own. Can you teach me how to do it? or anyone who could teach me how to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I wrote a extended CountDownTimer [here](https://github.com/huynguyennovem/Android-CountDownTimer-Ext). Let's try this and leave your comment:

Eg:

```kotlin
// Init timer
lateinit var timerExt: CountDownTimerExt

timerExt = object : CountDownTimerExt(TIMER_DURATION, TIMER_INTERVAL) {
    override fun onTimerTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onTimerTick $millisUntilFinished")
    }

    override fun onTimerFinish() {
        Log.d("MainActivity", "onTimerFinish")
    }

}

// Start/Resume timer
timerExt.start()

// Pause timer
timerExt.pause()

// Restart timer
timerExt.restart()
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try using a library I created, [Hourglass](https://github.com/groverankush/Hourglass)

```
Hourglass hourglass = new Hourglass(50000, 1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTimerTick(long timeRemaining) {
            // Update UI
            Toast.show(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(timeRemaining), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTimerFinish() {
            // Timer finished
            Toast.show(MainActivity.this, "Timer finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    };
```

Use `hourglass.startTimer();` to start the timer.

It has helper methods which allow to pause and resume the timer.

```
hourglass.pauseTimer();
```

AND

```
hourglass.resumeTimer();
```

Comment: My compliments for making this wonderful tool, but please make sure you disclose your affiliations, as I see that this is made by you.

Comment: @Ankush brother,  onTimerTick() is being called if I call pauseTimer(). How can I stop this?

Answer (score 3):

I have a simple solution. All you have to do is add an extra variable which stores the current time. The only addition is **currentMillis** at top and in onTick(). Use cancel() to pause.
**PS:** I'm using butterknife library, it's used to avoid using findviewbyid and setonclicklisteners. If you do not want to use it then you can just use the basic way of setting listeners and findviewbyid.

```
@BindView(R.id.play_btn) ImageButton play;
@BindView(R.id.pause_btn) ImageButton pause;
@BindView(R.id.close_btn) ImageButton close;
@BindView(R.id.time) TextView time;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private long currentMillis=10;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

@OnClick(R.id.play_btn) void play_game(){
    this.play();
}

@OnClick(R.id.pause_btn) void pause_game(){
    this.pause();
}

@OnClick(R.id.close_btn) void close_game(){
    this.close();
}

void play(){
    play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    close.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    time.setText(""+currentMillis);
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(currentMillis*1000,1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinish) {
            currentMillis=millisUntilFinish/1000;
            time.setText(""+millisUntilFinish/1000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            time.setText("Done!");
        }
    };

    countDownTimer.start();
}

void pause(){
    play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    close.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    countDownTimer.cancel();
}

void close(){
    if(countDownTimer!=null){
        countDownTimer.cancel();
        countDownTimer=null;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Although the question doesn't include the Kotlin tag, I still think this answer belongs here due to Android tag.

I've made a very simple library that uses the `CountDownTimer` internally and inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8306456/2304737). So far, it works as intended with my very basic use case:

> Pause the timer when the app/activity is paused, and resume when the app/activity resumes.

#### Usage:

```
class GameActivity : Activity() {

    private var timer = CustomTimer(30000, 1000) // 30 seconds duration at 1 second interval

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        ...
        timer.onTick = { millisUntilFinished ->
            textView.text = "seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000
        }
        timer.onFinish = {
            TODO("do something here")
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        timer.resume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        timer.pause()
    }
}
```

#### Source code:

Resumable [CustomTimer.kt](https://gist.github.com/mr5z/e997cd23844b9461f84d5ceede0e4c86) (50 lines)

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void setTimerMillis(Context context, long millis)
 { SharedPreferences sp = 
context.getSharedPreferences(SessionManager.FILE_USER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor spe = sp.edit(); spe.putLong(SessionManager.TIMER_MILLIS, millis); spe.apply(); }



       void setExamTimer() {
            setTimerColors();
            final long maxTimeToShow = 60000;            //testing
            final long lastTimeinMillisLeftSaved = TestyBookHelper.getTimerMillis(context); //take saved value from sharedpref
            final long intervalTime = 1000;
            donut_exam_timer.setMax((int) maxTimeToShow);
            CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(lastTimeinMillisLeftSaved, intervalTime) {
                @Override
                public void onTick(long millis) {
                    TestyBookHelper.setTimerMillis(context, millis);
                    String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));               System.out.println(hms);
                    donut_exam_timer.setText(hms);
                    donut_exam_timer.setProgress(millis);
                }
                @Override
                public void onFinish() {
                }
            };
            countDownTimer.start();
        }

  public static long getTimerMillis(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sp = context.getSharedPreferences(SessionManager.FILE_USER, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sp.getLong(SessionManager.TIMER_MILLIS, 60000L);}
```

Comment: just keep timeLeft of countdown in sharepreference and here we go.

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others. Thanks for improving the answer's reference value and making it more understandable!

Comment: Please use sharedpreference to save your last time left in millis and when you open app again, take the last save time left in millis

Comment: If you want to add further informations to your answer, please [edit] it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code. I hope this simple and helpful.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private long startMillis = 10000; //milliseconds the start value
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private Button btnStart;
private boolean isStarted;
private long remainderMillis// get remaing milli seconds


protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    this.Init();
StartTime()



}

private void Init() {
    isStarted = false;
   
    remainderMillis = startMillis; // remaingMillis equals startMillis at the first start
    this.btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { // Start pause controller button
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isStarted){
                PauseGame();
            }else{
                StartGame();
            }
        }
    });
}
private void StartTimer(){
    this.countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(remaingMillis,1000) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            remainderMillis = millisUntilFinished;

            int totalSecs = (int)millisUntilFinished/1000; //convert to seconds
            int minutes = (totalSecs%3600)/60; // Convert to minutes
            int seconds = totalSecs%60; // Convert to seconds
            String timeString = String.format("%02d:%02d",minutes,seconds); // Formatting to mm:ss
            countDownView.setText(timeString); // Display in textview
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
    // Beeping if the timer onfinish
            ToneGenerator toneGenerator = new ToneGenerator(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,100);
            toneGenerator.startTone(ToneGenerator.TONE_CDMA_PIP,500);


        }
    }.start();
    btnStart.setImageResource(R.mipmap.pause); //change button image to Pause mipmap
}
private void PauseTimer(){
    isStarted = false;
    countDownTimer.cancel(); //You can cancel here the countDownTimer, but the current milliseconds store in the remainderMillis variable, so in the StartTimer() void can be contiune the timer
    btnStart.setImageResource(R.mipmap.play);


}
```

}