# Android: Resume on Count Down Timer

Tags: android

I am a beginner in Java and Android programming.  And I am confused on how to resume my Count Down Timer
   after the `pause. counter.ontick(milisUntilFinished);` is not working in my code.
   Please help me I am bit rushed.

This is my code:

```
@Override  
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle cute) {  
super.onRestoreInstanceState(cute);}  

@Override  
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {  
super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);}  

Timer.setOnClickListener(TimerClickListener);  
counter = new MyCount(orig, 1000);  
private OnClickListener TimerClickListener = new OnClickListener() {  

public void onClick(View v) {  
if (p1<=4){  
if (decision==0){  
counter.start();  
decision=1;}  
else if(decision==1){  
//pause
counter.cancel();  
decision=2; }  
else{  
//resume  
counter.onTick(orig);  
decision=1;   
}  
//end if  
}   } };      
class MyCount extends CountDownTimer {  
public MyCount(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {  
super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);  
public void onFinish() {  
//do stuff  
}//end if  
}//finish  
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {  
. . .  
. . .    
orig = millisUntilFinished;  
Timer.setText(String.format("%02d", minutes) + ":"  
+ String.format("%02d", seconds));  
}//class MyCount
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306374/android-how-to-pause-and-resume-a-count-down-timer

Comment: dont ask question again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot pause a countdown timer. Once you use

```
counter.cancel();
```

you actually cancel out the timer altogether.

What you can actually do is to start a new countdown timer once you decide to resume, off course with new parameters.

Comment: I did what you said but it reset not resume  
//resume
countresume = new MyCount(timeleft, 1000);
counter.start();
decision=1; 
}

timeleft should contain the value of the timer as it stops.

Comment: when the timer pauses, store the value (desiredTime - timeTickedUntilPaused), and then when you wanto resume the timer...restart a new timer with this stored value.

Comment: Sorry Im confused on how to store the variable. I did was to reset rather than resume. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Better you can use the [Chronometer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Chronometer.html) View .Sample is [here](http://android-pro.blogspot.com/2010/06/android-chronometer-timer.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
 final CountDownTimer cdt=new CountDownTimer(x,y)
            {
                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                 mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                 c= millisUntilFinished;
                 if(cover==6)
                 onFinish();

            }
                 public void onFinish()
                 {                                   
                 Integer i=(Integer) cover*10;
                 String s=i.toString();
                 mTextField.setText("done! "+s);
                 for(int k=1;k<=12;k++)
                       b[k].setClickable(false);

                }            
        }.start();


> define c as long variable assign it to the value of millisUntilFinished and restart the counter with c value as the starting value....

       final CountDownTimer cdt1=new CountDownTimer(c,y)
                        {
                             public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
                             mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                             c= millisUntilFinished;
                             if(cover==6)
                             onFinish();
                        }
                             public void onFinish()
                             {                                   
                              Integer i=(Integer) cover*10;
                              String s=i.toString();
                              mTextField.setText("done! "+s);
                             }           
                        }.start();

this code will virtually give u a Countdowntimer with pause and resume control
```