# Can not use a Runnable

Tags: java, android

I'm using a `Runnable` as a `Timer` that alternatively runs a block.

I got this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857590/android-countdowntimer-skips-last-ontick/8858608#8858608) and changed it as such:

```
public class TikingTimer {

    private long countDownInterval;
    private boolean status;
    public TikingTimer(long pCountDownInterval) {
        this.countDownInterval = pCountDownInterval;
        status = false;
        Initialize();
    }

    public void Stop() {
        status = false;
    }

    public void Start() {
        status = true;
    }
    public void Initialize() 
    {
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        final Runnable counter = new Runnable(){

            public void run(){
                if(status) {


                    //TODO my code


                } else {
                    handler.postDelayed(this, countDownInterval);
                }
            }
        };

        handler.postDelayed(counter, countDownInterval);
    }
}
```

... and at `onCreate` method I used :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        TikingTimer tt = new TikingTimer(1000);
        tt.Start();
    }
```

But when I run the project, it force-closes.

Is it wrong to use `Runnable` at `onCreate` method?

Thanks.

The LogCat stack trace is:

```
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{kawthar.taghvimdigital/kawthar.taghvimdigital.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at kawthar.taghvimdigital.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:14)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1319)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
08-11 13:04:55.384: E/AndroidRuntime(3125):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please edit and add full stacktrace from your logcat.

Comment: Do you override the constructor of your Activity? The stacktrace looks like you're calling findViewById() from the Activity's constructor..

Comment: Can you post the complete OnCreate code, for us to review. Because the problem isn't in the runnable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your MainActivity (not posted), at line **14**, you are looking up a `View` through method:

```
findViewById(Activity.java:1839)
```

... which is not found.

Since you manipulate this view somehow, the `NullPointerException` you posted is thrown.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a view that is not defined in your xml layout of the main activity.

Check the Line 14 on your MainActivity

This issue is not due to Runnable.