# Display CountDownTimer timer on a TextView

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I have a simple program that displays a different text to a `textview` after 5 seconds which looks like this:

```
textView1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textView2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);

    new CountDownTimer(5000,5000) 
    {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

        }


        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            textView1.setText("text changed");
        }
    }.start();
```

want to display the timer as it counts `(like 5, 4, 3, 2 , 1)` in the `TextView2`

but I can't seem to figure out how.

Help, anyone? Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8857590/android-countdowntimer-skips-last-ontick

Comment: Check out this : https://github.com/Shubhamsdr3/timertextview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?
Taken from http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         textView2.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         textView1.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();
```