# Count down timer how to implement onfinish method

Tags: java, android, android-studio, countdowntimer

I have a countdown timer that i want to implement  on finish method or some kind of code so that when the timer stops, the text views change to *Time's up* **and another method is initiated (in the activity)**.
To clarify, the timer is given a starting number that counts down from, to zero in format of `xx:xx`.

The class of the timer :

```
public class countdown_timer {
private  long pls;
private long millisInFuture;
private long countDownInterval;
private boolean status;
public countdown_timer(long pMillisInFuture, long pCountDownInterval) {
    this.millisInFuture = pMillisInFuture;
    this.countDownInterval = pCountDownInterval;
    this.pls = pMillisInFuture;

    status = false;
    Initialize();
}

public void Stop() {
    status = false;
}
public  void Reset() {
    millisInFuture = pls;
}

public long getCurrentTime() {
    return millisInFuture;
}

public void Start() {
    status = true;
}
public void Initialize()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    Log.v("status", "starting");
    final Runnable counter = new Runnable(){

        public void run(){
            long sec = millisInFuture/1000;
            if(status) {
                if(millisInFuture <= 0) {
                    Log.v("status", "done");
                } else {
                    Log.v("status", Long.toString(sec) + " seconds remain");
                    millisInFuture -= countDownInterval;
                    handler.postDelayed(this, countDownInterval);
                }
            } else {
                Log.v("status", Long.toString(sec) + " seconds remain and timer has stopped!");
                handler.postDelayed(this, countDownInterval);
            }
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(counter, countDownInterval);
}
```

The activty that the timer is used:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_game_2);
    //...find views
    mycounterup = new countdown_timer(startcard, 1000);
    mycounterdown = new countdown_timer(startcard, 1000);
    RefreshTimer();
    mycounterdown.Start();

  public void RefreshTimer()
{
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    final Runnable counter = new Runnable(){

        public void run(){
            int minutes_up_start = (int) (mycounterup.getCurrentTime() / 1000) / 60;
            int seconds_up_start = (int) (mycounterup.getCurrentTime() / 1000) % 60;
            String time_2_up_start_formatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes_up_start, seconds_up_start);
            card_2_up.setText(time_2_up_start_formatted);

            int minutes_down_start = (int) (mycounterdown.getCurrentTime() / 1000) / 60;
            int seconds_down_start = (int) (mycounterdown.getCurrentTime() / 1000) % 60;
            String card_2_down_start_formatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes_down_start, seconds_down_start);
            card_2_down.setText(card_2_down_start_formatted);
            handler.postDelayed(this, 100);
        }
    };

    handler.postDelayed(counter, 100);
}
```

Comment: You can try to extend `CountDownTimer` in your timer class

Comment: @Cagri Yalcin could you tell me how i do that pls

Comment: why you don't use builtin CountDownTimer class?

Comment: @godot what do you mean?

Comment: @manos check my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [CountDownTimer](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html):

```
new CountDownTimer(endsIn * 1000, 1000) { 
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) { 
           timerTextView.setText(String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished/1000);
 } 
public void onFinish() {
} 
}.start();
```

**OR:**

extend `CountDownTimer` class:

```
public class countdown_timer extends CountDownTimer {
    TextView textView;
    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisInFuture) {
        long sec = millisInFuture/1000;
            if(millisInFuture <= 0) {
                Log.v("status", "done");

        } else {
            Log.v("status", Long.toString(sec) + " seconds remain and timer has stopped!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        if(textView != null){
            // change text in your textview
        }
    }



    public countdown_timer(long pMillisInFuture, long pCountDownInterval) {
        super(pMillisInFuture, pCountDownInterval);

    }
    public countdown_timer(TextView textView, long pMillisInFuture, long pCountDownInterval) {
        super(pMillisInFuture, pCountDownInterval);
        this.textView = textView;




    }






}
```

here is a two constructors, one of them is the same as is in your example and in second one you can pass also `TextView` object and use it in `onFinish()` method.

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is `CountDownTimer` in the Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    CountDownTimer mycounterdown;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        long startcard = 10000;
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);

        mycounterdown = new CountDownTimer(startcard, 1000) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long mycounterup) {
                int minutes_up_start = (int) (mycounterup / 1000) / 60;
                int seconds_up_start = (int) (mycounterup / 1000) % 60;
                String time_2_up_start_formatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes_up_start, seconds_up_start);
                textView.setText(time_2_up_start_formatted);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // call here other methods from activity

                testMethod();
            }
        };
        mycounterdown.start();

    }
    public void testMethod(){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test Method called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**UPDATE 3:** if last tick is one, not zero change count down interval to 500 instead of 1000:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView;
    CountDownTimer mycounterdown;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        long startcard = 10000;
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test);

        mycounterdown = new CountDownTimer(startcard, 500) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long mycounterup) {
                int minutes_up_start = (int) (mycounterup / 1000) / 60;
                int seconds_up_start = (int) (mycounterup / 1000) % 60;
                String time_2_up_start_formatted = String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%02d:%02d", minutes_up_start, seconds_up_start);
                textView.setText(time_2_up_start_formatted);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                // call here other methods from activity

                testMethod();
            }
        };
        mycounterdown.start();

    }
    public void testMethod(){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Test Method called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

**NOTE:** take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12283400/3179389)

Comment: The problem is that with the conventional countdown timer the are many bugs like skipping the last tick,that's why i created a class for it

Comment: what you mean in skipping last tick?

Comment: if you mean last tick when time would be equal to zero then you can just write if(millisUntilFinished/1000!=0){ //do stuff }

Comment: Thanks for the help but i don't want to add a new CountDownTimer, i want to use the one i have in the timer class but with an on finish method

Comment: How can i initiate another method when timer stops?

Comment: method from Activity?

Comment: Yes a method from the activity

Comment: if you want to call activity methods why do you want to use custom count down timer and not this one I described first time  ?

Comment: because the custom one is more accurate

Comment: what kind of inaccuracy have you faced ?

Comment: the conventional one stops at 00:02 then counts 2 sec in the background and then the times up text is shown instead of showing 00:01 then 00:00 and then time's up

Comment: check it out again, I updated my answer. I tried to rewrite your logic without custom count down timer

Comment: Stops at 1 sec instead of 0

Answer (score 1):

First, extend `CountDownTimer` in your timer class.

```
public class countdown_timer extends CountDownTimer {

}
```

This allows you to implement some methods.

```
@Override
public void onTick(long l) {

}

@Override
public void onFinish() {

}
```

Also you must implement constructor that matches super class. You can also add some additional parameters. For example `TextView`

```
TextView textView;
public countdown_timer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, TextView txt) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    textView = txt;
}
```

The `onFinish()` is what you want. Also make sure you are using this class as a `CountDownTimer`. Then you will be able to start your timer.
Hope it helps.

Comment: When i extend the class to CountDownTimer it shows me error in:      public countdown_timer(long pMillisInFuture, long pCountDownInterval)      "There is no default constructor available"

Comment: You must implement constructor that matches your super class. Editing my answer

Comment: So far so good but the on finish method is in the timer class and not in my activity so i cant use it to change the text

Comment: You can change the constructor method to send your `Textview`. Check my edited answer

Comment: How can i initiate another method when timer stops?

Comment: Which method ?.

Comment: a custom method in my activity

Comment: You must use `onTick()` method to update your `TextViews`