# Pause and Continue CountDownTimer in Android

Tags: android, timer, countdowntimer

I know there are a lot of threads with the same topic, but I do not want to use some random code I do not understand.

This is my current code to pause and continue a CountDownTimer in Android Studio:

```
public void getReadyTimer(long time){
    time = 12000;
    progress=0;
    circularProgressBar.setProgress(0);
    //tvInfo.setText("Get Ready!");

    timer= new CountDownTimer(time, 1000) { 

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            milliLeft = millisUntilFinished;
            sec = ((millisUntilFinished-1000)/1000);
            tvTimer.setText(Long.toString(sec));
            //tvTimer.setText((millisUntilFinished-1000) / 1000 + ""); 
            progress++;
            int animationDuration = 1500; // 2500ms = 2,5s
            circularProgressBar.setProgressWithAnimation((int)progress*100/(11000/1000), animationDuration); 

            circularProgressBar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (t== 0) {
                        pauseTimer();
                        t =1 ;
                        tvInfo.setText(Integer.toString(t));
                    }else{
                        resumeTimer();
                        t = 0;
                        tvInfo.setText(Integer.toString(t));
                    }
                }
            });

        }

        private void pauseTimer(){
            timer.cancel();
        }

        private void resumeTimer(){
            Log.i("sec", Long.toString(sec));
            milliLeft = sec*1000;
            getReadyTimer(milliLeft);


        }

        public void onFinish() {
            if (circularProgressBar.getProgress() == 100) {
                startTimer();
            }
        }

    }.start();
}
```

However it does not work properly. The problem is, that the Timer (after pausing) starts again with the value "time" and not with "millileft" as it should be. I appreciate every kind of help.

Answer (score 1):

Use this, may help you

**Global Variables**

```
private CountDownTimer timer;
long time = 12000;
```

**Timer**

```
private void startTimer(long timerStartFrom) {
    timer = new CountDownTimer(timerStartFrom, 1000) {

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            //updating the global variable
            time = millisUntilFinished;

        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    }.start();
}
```

**In Initial(onCreate)**

**How to Start**

start your timer with

`startTimer(time)` as time has initial value  //`12000`

**How to Pause**

then you can pause/cancel `timer` by using `timer.cancel()`

**How to Resume**

and when you want to **resume** just start your timer by calling `startTimer(time)` as the timer has the updated value.

**What will it does**
it will start your timer with previous time where you have stops your timer

**Simple**, Happy coding :)

Comment: @Ketarr have you try this

Comment: How can you use the `timer` variable outside the function? Isn't it's scope limited to the `startTimer()` function?

Answer (score 0):

You are re-assigning the value of the passed parameter `milliLeft` to `12000`. To fix this you can create two methods. One which accepts a parameter and the other without. e.g.

```
public void getReadyTimer() {
    this.getReaderTimer(12000L); // default value
}

public void getReadyTimer(long time) {}
```

In the parameterized method remove the assignation of

`time = 12000;`

Comment: When I use the first method, how can I assign milliLeft to getReadyTimer()?

Comment: @Ketarr You would use the second method and call it `getReadyTimer(milliLeft)`.

Comment: Hmm.. It throws: milliLeft cannot be applied to (long)

Comment: @Ketarr I forgot to add the suffix `L`. Use `this.getReaderTimer(12000L)` for the default value

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn´t call `timer.cancel()` to pause the timer. And afterwards you can call timer.resume() to start it again. There is no need to use so "complicated" logic.

Have a look here:
[Android: timer start, pause, stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8306374/android-how-to-pause-and-resume-a-count-down-timer)