# How to pause the count down timer in android?

Tags: android

In my application I kept **pause button and start button**. **By default I set the timer to 50sec.** When the timer is running I wrote the onclick action code for each button...i.e when pause button is clicked the time is pausing and again when start button is clicked **it is again starting from 50sec**. **But it should start from the time where it is paused.** How can I do that?

Please help me....thanks in advance.......

My Code:

```
long timervalue = 50000;

btn13 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.pause);
btn14 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.resume);

final CountDownTimer Counter1 = new CountDownTimer(timervalue, 1000) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            time.setText(formatTime(millisUntilFinished));

            btn13.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {  
                    Counter1.cancel();
                }

     });
            btn14.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(View v)
                {  

                    Counter1.start();

                }

     });

        }
public void onFinish()
 {
    Counter1.cancel();
}
};



public String formatTime(long millis) {
        String output = "00:00";
        long seconds = millis / 1000;
        // long minutes = seconds / 60;

        seconds = seconds % 60;
        // minutes = minutes % 60;

        String secondsD = String.valueOf(seconds);
        // String minutesD = String.valueOf(minutes);

        if (seconds < 10)
            secondsD = "0" + seconds;
        // if (minutes < 10)
        // minutesD = "0" + minutes;

        output = secondsD;
        return output;
    }
```

Comment: I'm a WP7 developer but this will surely help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510433/countdown-timer-required-on-android

Comment: Post your code snippet, so we could take a look at it and suggest you some ideas based on your code.

Comment: > Refer this Link  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138348/how-to-stop-cancel-android-countdowntimer

Comment: Hi I edited my code ..please go through it once and help me in achieving that task...will be thankful

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you cannot pause CountDownTimer, but there are other ways to do what you want to do.

try this:

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private CountDownTimer ct;
    private long ts = 30;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        final TextView mTextField = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        final Button bt = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.bt);

         bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(bt.getText().toString().equals("Start")){
                    bt.setText("Stop");
                     ct =  new CountDownTimer(ts*1000, 1000) {

                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                                mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                                ts = millisUntilFinished/1000;
                            }

                            public void onFinish() {
                                mTextField.setText("done!");
                            }
                         }.start();
                }
                else{
                    bt.setText("Start");
                    ct.cancel();}
            }
        });
   }
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for the response..I tried your code but it is showing error at line ct.cancel();....Also I edited my code...please check it once...