# Android countdown from one date to another

Tags: android

I'm trying to countdown from a start date to an end date. For example, on 12 October 2012 to 14 October 2012.

I would like to get the current date and from this date do the countdown to the next.

Do you have any good examples?

Comment: What do you mean by "countdown"? This post has a good example of using countdown timers: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3510433/241294

Comment: This means that I will count down from one date to another example showing that the remaining 12 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might prove too inflexible a solution but you could try converting the dates to long values, subtracting one from the other, and then using the android countdown timer class to do your countdown.

```
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date a = null, b = null;
    try {
        a = sdf.parse("14-10-2012");
        b = sdf.parse("12-10-2012");
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //      .getTime() does the conversion: Date --> long
    CountDownTimer cdt = new CountDownTimer(a.getTime() - b.getTime(), 1000) {

        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void onFinish() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    }.start();
```

more information about the class can be found here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html